# How to add child css file under .cshtml in .net core & visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I noticed by default in .NET 7 mvc project under .cshtml file also .css file added but I tried to do same for my custom .cshtml file and I coudnt found option for that. Check picture for better understanding. How can I do it? Can anyone add brief description for such sub files? Why they exists and how to attach them in .cshtml?

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as CSS isolation, that is if you are looking to add a style file to a page. If you are not looking to add a .css file than stop here.

Basic steps using Index page but can be done with any page.

1. Right click on Pages folder
2. Add a new item, select text file
3. Save the text file as Index.cshtml.css which will nest the new file under Index.cshtml as shown below.
4. Add styles into Index.cshtml.css
5. Open Index.cshtml and add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/@(nameof(IsolationWebApp)).styles.css" />`. Replace IsolationWebApp with the namespace of your project (easy to get from Program.cs)
6. In Index.cshtml add one or more elements that use the styles in Index.cshtml.css

[image]

See also this [article](https://dev.to/karenpayneoregon/razor-pages-css-isolation-3f5) done with Razor Pages, same technique for ASP.NET